# Nested Loop in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a batch file to re organize files in a series of folders. The current layout is several folders with numeric names from '-12.60' to '-7.60'. In each of these folders, are a series of images numbered numerically from '00000.tiff' to '0006.tiff'

I run the following code, but seem to run into an error and can't find a solution for it. Any help will be much appreciated

```
for /L %%di IN (1,1,7) DO (
mkdir C:\Users\manu\Documents\ReOrdered_stacks\t%%di
for /L %%cm IN (7,1,12) DO (
  for /L %%mm IN (20,20,80) DO(
     rename "C:\Users\manu\Desktop\2015.07.24 11-57_r\Stack\Phase\%%cm.%%mm\0000%%di.tiff" %%cm.%%mm.tiff
     copy "C:\Users\manu\Desktop\2015.07.24 11-57_r\Stack\Phase\%%cm.%%mm\%%cm.%%mm.tiff" C:\Users\manu\Documents\ReOrdered_stacks\t%%di\
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: An error? Which error? Which line is affected?

Comment: The thing is I am new to batch files. I am assuming there is an error, but the cmd window closes before anything can be read. All I am able to figure out at this point is that the loop doesn't work because no files get copied.

Comment: Then start a command prompt and run the batch file from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Loop variables may only have one character
2. Parenthesis must be preceded by a space: `do (`
3. Run batch file from inside a command prompt console to see the syntax errors

---

```
for /L %%d IN (1,1,7) DO (
    mkdir C:\Users\manu\Documents\ReOrdered_stacks\t%%d
    for /L %%c IN (7,1,12) DO (
        for /L %%m IN (20,20,80) DO (
            rename "C:\Users\manu\Desktop\2015.07.24 11-57_r\Stack\Phase\%%c.%%m\0000%%d.tiff" %%c.%%m.tiff
            copy "C:\Users\manu\Desktop\2015.07.24 11-57_r\Stack\Phase\%%c.%%m\%%c.%%m.tiff" C:\Users\manu\Documents\ReOrdered_stacks\t%%d\
        )
    )
)
```

See [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) for more info on syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a nube at this so you guys are a huge help!!